# Extract a String out of a specific set of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a text as: 
sometext[string1 string2]someText

I want to retrieve string1 and string2 as separate strings from this text
How can i parse it in objective - c?

Comment: What's your `sometext` Is that an `Array` or what?

Comment: You can use a `NSRegularExpression` or `rangeOfString:`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution

```
  NSArray *arrayOne = [prettyFunctionString componentsSeparatedByString:@"["];
    NSString *parsedOne = [arrayOne objectAtIndex:1];

    NSArray *arrayTwo = [parsedOne componentsSeparatedByString:@"]"];
    NSString *parsedTwo = [arrayTwo objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *arrayThree = [parsedTwo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *className = [arrayThree objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *functionName = [arrayThree objectAtIndex:1];
```

thanks anyways

Comment: if anyone has better solution please post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work for you

```
NSString * string = @"sometext[string1 string2]sometext";
NSString * pattern = @"(.*)\[(.+) (.+)\](.*)"

NSRegularExpression * expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult * match = [expression firstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

if (match) {

    NSString * substring1 = [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
    NSString * substring2 = [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:3]];

    // do something with substring1 and substring2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this Simple Approach approach

```
NSString *str = @"sometext[string1 string2]someText";
NSInteger loc1 = [str localizedStandardRangeOfString:@"["].location;
NSInteger loc2 = [str localizedStandardRangeOfString:@"]"].location;
NSString *resultString = [str substringWithRange:(NSRange){loc1+1,loc2-loc1}];
NSArray *resultArry = [resultString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

result array will contain your required Reuslt

Answer (score 0):

For completeness - if you are trying to extract strings out of a string with a known pattern, then an `NSScanner` is the way to go.

This goes through the string in one pass.

```
NSString *string = @"sometext[string1 string2]someText";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

NSString *str1;
NSString *str2;

[scanner scanUpToString:@"[" intoString:nil]; // Scan up to the '[' character.
[scanner scanString:@"[" intoString:nil]; // Scan the '[' character and discard it.
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] intoString: &str1]; // Scan all the characters up to the whitespace and accumulate the characters into 'str1'
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] intoString:nil]; // Scan up to the next alphanumeric character and discard the result.
[scanner scanUpToString:@"]" intoString:&str2]; // Scan up to the ']' character, accumulate the characters into 'str2'

// Log the output.
NSLog(@"First String: %@", str1);
NSLog(@"Second String: %@", str2);
```

Which puts the output into the console of:

```
2015-09-23 11:31:02.522 StringExtractor[46678:4289499] First String: string1
2015-09-23 11:31:02.522 StringExtractor[46678:4289499] Second String: string2
```